# Does use of foreign key in EDM of MVC slowers execution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, edmx, ado.net-entity-data-model

> If EDM for 3 Tables is as shown in figer given below.

[image: Image of]

then,

1. is it good approach to use such foreign keys in EDM and in DB ?
2. can such DB design slower down execution ?
3. which architecture will be preferable with use of foreign key or
   without use of foreign key ?

if any one want data from table-3 from id of TAble-1

then it can be done in 2 ways.

I.

> db.TAble_1.FirstOrDefault(m => m.TAble_1ID == 2).Table_2.FirstOrDefault().TAble_3;

II.

> By Join in LINQ

4. So which one is faster ?

if any one want data from table-1 from id of TAble-3

then it can be done in 2 ways.

I.

> db.TAble_1.FirstOrDefault(m => m.TAble_3ID == 2).Table_2.TAble_3;

II.

> By Join in LINQ

5. So which one is faster ?

Thank You all ,in advance.

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on the [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: This question is regarding LINQ and EDM for asp.net MVC thats why i asked question here.

Comment: "Which one is faster" is answered by measuring it. Run it one way, then run it the other, time both and compare the results.

Comment: Also in general it does not help naming tables Table1 and Table2 etc. It's not a good practice and it also does not allow people here making any inference how your data may be used - and this is *very* important when designing data structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, Basically what is EDM or Lets take an example of Linq to Sql, It is just a converter of your Object Queries to SQL, and then it fires the same as the Inline query , using a SqlConnection object.

This Question is two - fold :

1. Is the Database Design Proper? - Coz this is actually going to Make a Difference in the Performance. Design makes the Core of the Queries, its refining can take care of most of your Performance issues.
2. EDMX , Linq To Sql, Entity Framework or some other ORM (Object Relational Mappers) : Normally why would one use a ORM? Since they have small queries and they are not very proficient into SQL Server, or they want the Learning curve for the Developers to be blunt comparatively, and need to right the simple small queries at their ease and pretty Rapidly (Having a Stored procedure for a Simple Select doesnt make sense.) So it solves your problems by Converting your Object Queries (LINQ) to Sql statements.

Answer for your Case:
It depends on for which queries you use the same, The queries which you have stated it wont make difference if it has joins, (Considering your Design is proper.) EDM , or anything stated above is fine for any of such queries,

But yes dont use it for **"TOO BIG QUERIES"** or dont Replace **Stored Procedures** with this since what happens is it converts your Object queries to SQL statements, sends it to the DB Server , Sql Server Engine parses the Queries, and then Executes; So in case the Queries are too big then in that case the Network Latency, Compilations of the Queries, (& since the Queries are just being Compiled it doesnt compile the Execution plan.) whereas in case of Stored Procedures it is already there and the Queries run pretty faster

Useful links:

[Execution Plan](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9990/SQL-Tuning-Tutorial-Understanding-a-Database-Execu)